# After executing script in Response header : connection is getting closed

Tags: jmeter

After executing script, in Response Header: connection close message is getting displayed.(As this is the first HTTP Request)

I have recorded a script with the help of `HTTP Test Script Recorder`.
In the first request, there is no any field captured. But after executing script in Response Header:Connection Close message is displayed.

```
Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: BrowserId=vbT9Hz0WSDmhVby-u9ryJQ;Path=/;Domain=.xxxxx.com;Expires=Sat, 13-Apr-2019 08:52:51 GMT;Max-Age=5184000
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536002; includeSubDomains
Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only: pin-sha256="9n0izTnSRF+W4W4JTq51avSXkWhQB8duS2bxVLfzXsY="; pin-sha256="5kJvNEMw0KjrCAu7eXY5HZdvyCS13BbA0VJG1RSP91w="; pin-sha256="njN4rRG+22dNXAi+yb8e3UMypgzPUPHlv4+foULwl1g="; max-age=86400; includeSubDomains; report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/hpkp-report/00Dq0000000DFMbm";
Expect-CT: max-age=0; report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/Expect-CT-report/00Dq0000000DFMbm";
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests 
X-Robots-Tag: none
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin
Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are totally sure that the connection doesn't need to be closed after the first request you can tick `Use Keep-Alive` box at the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler level

[image]

This way JMeter will send [Connection: keep-alive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Keep-Alive) header along with the request hence the connection will not be closed after the request is done (which is more or less in line with what real browsers should be doing - they open a TCP stream and send requests over a single TCP connection)

However your situation might be different, I would recommend capturing the real headers sent by the real browser using [browser developers tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) or a sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and make sure JMeter sends the same headers (you can use [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to add the [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) of your choice to the request )

Answer (score 0):

Add a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your test plan.

Also, check this [quick JMeter Recording guide](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/01/jmeter-recording/) for getting started